# Application crashes when it tries to launch Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a splash screen that i want to run before my main app screen. However, when the timer ends, the applicaiton crashes. Any ideas on why this happens? Thanks in advance.

Below is the referenced code

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            // Whatever is enclosed in the {} of method run(), runs when we
            // start the application
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {

                    Intent openMainScreen = new Intent("com.package.Main_Screen");
                    startActivity(openMainScreen);

                }
            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat error report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply use this kind of Intent,

```
Intent openMainScreen = new Intent(Splash.this,Main_Screen.class);
startActivity(openMainScreen);
```

And also make sure you you have added the Activity in your manifest like this,

```
<activity android:name=".Main_Screen">
 </activity>
```

Comment: You know, i tried to call it like this and i was getting an error. I had to change my manifest as you suggested in order to call it like this Intent openMainScreen = new Intent(Splash.this,Main_Screen.class); Thank you

Comment: No problems.. You are weolcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Write below code

```
Intent openMainScreen = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(openMainScreen);
```

instead of

```
Intent openMainScreen = new Intent("com.package.Main_Screen");
startActivity(openMainScreen);
```

And declare your MainActivity into Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. As it truns out i had to change my manifest as well

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `startActivity` from different `Thread`.You have to run it from `UI` `thread`.What you are trying to achieve can be done easily by

```
    public class Splash extends Activity {
        Handler handler;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Intent openMainScreen = new Intent(Splash.this,
                            Main_Screen.class);
                    startActivity(openMainScreen);

                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call like this

```
Intent openMainScreen = new Intent(ClassName.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(openMainScreen);
```

And you have to register it in Manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```